# Why System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative is occuring when i change the page no. in gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.This error is showing if I change the page number in grid view.In first page every rows are working correctly but after first page if I click on any row it is showing the error.

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
            For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView_modify.Rows
                If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                    row.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.textDecoration='underline';"
                    row.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"


                    row.Attributes("onclick") = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView_modify, "Select$" & row.DataItemIndex, True)

            Next

            MyBase.Render(writer)
        End Sub




        Protected Sub GridView_modify_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView_modify.SelectedIndexChanged

            PanelModify.Visible = True

            connection.ConnectionString = connectionstringdb
            Try

                connection.Open()


                Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView_modify.SelectedRow

                test1 = DirectCast(GridView_modify.SelectedRow.Cells(1).FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField).Value
                lbl_slno.Text = test1
                selectAllFieldsUpdate()

                txt_tenderDate_update.Text = GridView_modify.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text  ' or  'Text1.Value = row.Cells[1].Text; 
                txt_sub_update.Text = GridView_modify.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
                txt_lastdate_udpate.Text = GridView_modify.SelectedRow.Cells(3).Text

            Catch ce As Exception
                Response.Write(ce.ToString())



            Finally
                connection.Close()

            End Try

            connection.Close()
        End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView_modify_PageIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView_modify.PageIndexChanged
        Filldatagrid()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub GridView_modify_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridView_modify.PageIndexChanging
        GridView_modify.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex

    End Sub


    Public Sub Filldatagrid()

        connection.ConnectionString = connectionstringdb
        Try
            connection.Open()

            Dim strsql1 As String = ("SELECT SlNo,Subject,convert(varchar(10),[TenderDate],105) as TenderDate,convert(varchar(10),[Lastdate],105) as Lastdate,Filename from TenderTable order by convert(datetime, Tenderdate, 105) Desc")

            Dim mydatadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(strsql1, connection)
            Dim mydataset As New DataSet
            mydatadapter.Fill(mydataset, "TenderTable")
            GridView_modify.DataSource = mydataset.Tables("TenderTable")
            GridView_modify.DataBind()
            connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.ToString())
            connection.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Could you post complete exception stacktrace to make it more clear where is the origin of the exception?

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.get_SelectedRow() at ModifyTender.GridView_modify_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\KsphcinWeb\TendersNews\ModifyTender.aspx.vb:line 124

Comment: so the problem is inside "GridView_modify_SelectedIndexChanged" - could you write what code exactly is at line 124? Are you sure there are any cells in "GridView_modify.SelectedRow"?

Comment: Please don't post your exception text in a comment!  _Edit_ your question and add the text there.

Comment: Dim row As GridViewRow = GridView_modify.SelectedRow is line no. 124

Comment: Ok - could you remove any 'commented code' from your sample above so that it can be easily understood and change sample to be "complete"/compilable?

Comment: I have removed all the comments from my sample. Plz help me because its important for me.